# NMock3 How to Mock a method with out parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nmock

I have a method that has one of its parameters as out, I found a reference on how to Mock it in NMock2. However, it seems the NMock3 has major changes that break the solution from NMock2.
Here's the Interface signature for my method:

```
 IEnumerable<Video> DeletedVideos(int index, int pageSize, out int totalCount);
```

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this, it is a reasonable question and the lack of examples for NMock3 is very frustrating if you are forced to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that I found after trial and error

```
_mockObject
.Expects.One.Method(m =>
        m.DeletedVideos(-1, -1, out ignoredValue)) //values are ignored
       .With(0, 20, Is.Out) //set the values manually
       .Will(new SetIndexedParameterAction(2, 100) , Return.Value(deletedVideos));
```

When this method is invoked from my controller, NMock3 will pass 0, 20 as the first two parameters (Int32), and it will return the IEnumerable with 3rd Int as 100.

To use SetIndexedParameterAction you need to add the namespace "NMock.Actions".

new SetIndexedParameterAction (2, 100) where 2 is the index of the parameter and 100 is the value to be returned.

Return.Value (deletedVideos) is the value to be returned by the method.